# Addition of an array elements in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

*/* I am trying to add array elements in c using myfun() but compiler shows warning
[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'myfun' from incompatible pointer type */*

```
#include<stdio.h>
void myfun(int*);
void main()
{
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11};
    printf("Array Elements are : ");
    myfun(&a);
}
void myfun(int* a)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d\t",a[i]);
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }   
    printf("\n\nSum : %d",sum);
}
```

Comment: You can just call `myfun(a)` - `a` will be converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void myfun(int*);
void main()
{
    int a[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11};
    printf("Array Elements are : ");
    myfun(a);
}
void myfun(int* a)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d\t",a[i]);
        sum = sum + a[i];
    }   
    printf("\n\nSum : %d",sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a already has type convertable to int*, you don't need use &a